# Can I modify the value of a self.var defined in __init__ in a class in an imported module?

Tags: python, video, hash

I'm importing a module (VideoHash) through pip which has a hard-coded value that I would like to change:

```
class VideoHash:
    def __init__(
        self,
    ) -> None:
        self.bits_in_hash = 64
```

I need to change `self.bits_in_hash` to 128, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I thought maybe I could just declare it like so:

```
from videohash import VideoHash

VideoHash.bits_in_hash = 128
```

But that didn't work. I'm out of my depth here, so I'm not sure where to go next.

Comment: You either need an object of type `VideoHash` and change its attribute or you have to set the `__init__` of `VideoHash` to a new constructor which calls the original constructor and then sets the attribute of the created object.

Comment: You're using Monkey Patching to achieve this, but this approach is only valuable for class variables, not instance variables. So, in order to do this, just create a custom subclass inheriting from VideoHash, and use that class in your code.

Comment: It may be wishful thinking that merely modifying the value will result in a 128-bit hash. Does the documentation or source code indicate that a 128-bit hash is supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a subclass and override the `__init__` function.

```
class VideoHash:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.bits_in_hash = 64

class MyVideoHash(VideoHash):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(MyVideoHash, self).__init__()
        self.bits_in_hash = 128

hash = VideoHash()
myhash = MyVideoHash()
print(hash.bits_in_hash)   # 64
print(myhash.bits_in_hash) # 128
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with that library, but since it looks like an instance variable, you need to alter it after creating an instance of it.

```
video_hash = VideoHash()
video_hash.bits_in_hash = 128
```

I doubt you can change it in a way that automatically sets it to `128` every time you initialise a new instance (except for something mentioned later), but you can create a custom function for it.

```
def create_custom_videohash():
    video_hash = VideoHash()
    video_hash.bits_in_hash = 128
    return video_hash
```

I also don't know if there is anything in that class or its functions which will break if the bits are changed, or if there is an existing function to do so. You could also try overwriting its `__init__` function, but unless you know how to do it properly this could be risky.